# TabBarController: Add/Remove from Array

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, uitabbarcontroller

i have a tabbarcontroller with two view controller. in my tabbarcontroller class I have an array `tasks = [Task]()` (same in each view controller). tasks are loaded with NSKeyedUnarchiver from the document directory.

I grab that tasks in each view controller with `tasks = (tabBarController as! TabBarController).tasks`.

In each view controller I can change properties for a task, but I can´t add (in view controller 1) or delete (in view controller 2) a Task.

after changing a property i save the tasks (in each view controller).

How do I add/delete tasks?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Arrays are value types in Swift, so when you modify `tasks` you are modifying a copy of `tabBarController.tasks`.  When you subsequently save `tabBarController.tasks` you are saving the original, unmodified, array.

You need to update the `tasks` array directly on the tab bar controller

```
var tabBarController = tabBarController as! TabBarController
tabBarController.tasks.append(newTask)
```

Presumably the objects *inside* your `tasks` array are `Class` instances (I'll call them `Task` objects), which means that they are reference types. Both the `tasks` array and the `tabBarController.tasks` array will hold references to the same `Task` objects, so if you simply modify a `Task` property, you are modifying the same instance of that object regardless of which array you used to access the object.

This is why property changes are saved, but addition/deletions aren't.

Comment: ok. i´ll try it, but why it saves the values of the properties? In tabbarcontroller I loaded the tasks one times and save the properties to the copies in the view controllers. for properties all works well only add/remove don't work.

Comment: Thanks. Now I´ve understood.